# Div not moving at bottom

Tags: html, alignment

I have created fiddle and there is one div called `lowestDiv` which i want at bottom but its coming in middle.

How can i move it to bottom and aligning to left of screen.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0s0vw6n/2/)

This is part of div in my fiddle code which i want to move down after div named `middleDiv`

```
<div ¨id= "lowestDiv" style="width: 954px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
    This div should be at bottom 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 <div ¨id= "lowestDiv" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;width: 954px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; background:red;">
        This div should be at bottom 
    </div>
```

I would ***seriously*** consider removing your inline styling though, to make this whole page **much easier to read (amongst many other pros)**:

```css
#lowestDiv {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 954px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="lowestDiv">
  This div should be at bottom
</div>
```

Comment: This is moving div to bottom after all my other divs in my actual page

Comment: @Happy: Is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry but there are few more divs below that div. i only want to move it below the other div named "middleDiv" . Here is updated fiddle

Comment: @Happy: please extract your inline styling, and place them either as classes in your css, or target through ids. As it currently is, people are having to combat this bad practise, with ***more*** bad practise just to make it work!

Comment: My actual page is not like this. I am using css. This is made to explain my problem

Comment: @Happy: This makes it *really* difficult to see what's happening. Could you edit with the 'reformatted' inline styling? Since the way could be altered depending on inline styles or css sheets.

Comment: I removed lot of html from my fiddle. This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d0s0vw6n/5/

Comment: Or reformat your code, and use display: block [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/d0s0vw6n/7/)

Comment: Your output is still wrong i am afraid. The div (lowestdiv) is coming in line of  the  text "Fakta, tall og informasjon." The div should be below it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72744/discussion-between-jbutler483-and-happy).